# Misplaced page content material-ui layout with react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, electron, material-ui

I'm working on a react page using material-ui within electron. The main page should have an AppBar with Toolbar and Drawer components.

I have copied the source code from https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/ for it. Everything works fine, except the placing of the content. I have placed a react router in the main tag this way:

```html
<main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
    <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={DeviceWithProps} />
        <Route path='/Dashboard' component={() =>
            <Dashboard />
        } />
        <Route path='/Quit' component={this._quit} />
        <Route path='/Device' component={() => DeviceWithProps} />
        <Route path='/Report' component={() => <Report />} />
        <Route path='/Settings' component={Settings} />
        <Route path='/About' component={() => <About version={currentVersion} />} />
        <Route path='/Help' component={() => <Help />} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
    </Router>
</main>
```

with the following styles:

```js
appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
},
```

The problem is that the content is rendered horizontally, right besides the Appbar/Toolbar and I cannot figure out why. It looks like the following:

[image: page content rendered in wrong position]

What is missing or how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to place it vertically other than horizontally?

Comment: `flexDirection: 'column'`?

Comment: Yes, the content should be right under the AppBar. The root item is defined this way:  root: { display: 'flex' }. I don't know why the content is placed horizontally.

Comment: flexdirection did the job but now the page content is covered by the drawer. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: can you upload a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adapting the styling. The following styles has been declared:

```
root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
},
content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 7 + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 7 + 1,
    }
},
contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 240,
},
```

And the component structure is as follows:

```
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Navbar
                    drawerOpened={drawerOpened}
                    onDrawerOpened={this._handleDrawerOpen}
                    onDrawerClosed={this._handleDrawerClose}
                />
                <main className={classNames(classes.content, {[classes.contentShift]: drawerOpened, })} >
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={DeviceWithProps} />
                            <Route path='/Dashboard' component={() =>
                                <Dashboard />
                            } />
                            <Route path='/Quit' component={this._quit} />
                            <Route path='/Device' component={DeviceWithProps} />
                            <Route path='/Report' component={() => <Report />} />
                            <Route path='/Settings' component={Settings} />
                            <Route path='/About' component={() => <About version={currentVersion} />} />
                            <Route path='/Help' component={() => <Help />} />
                            <Route component={NotFound} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </main> 
             </div>
```

The flexDirection fixed the problem of the horizontal appearance. The covering of the content was fixed by applying styles for the corresponding state of the drawer. The drawer state is passed by props to the Appbar/Toolbar/Drawer and depending on the drawer state the content is moved to the correct position.